# "This Emacs session has clients" - how do I find out why?

Tags: emacs

Every now and then, on C-x C-c Emacs announces "This Emacs session has clients; exit anyway?".

(I'm using Emacs 24beta at windows 7, in case that matters.)

I expected some files to be open that had been opened via emacsclientw.exe - but I don't see any.

(I have
git config --global core.editor "/c/lang/emacs-24beta/bin/emacsclientw.exe")

Is there any way to find out which buffers have clients? (Or is there anything else to look for?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there any way to find out which buffers have clients?

When a buffer has clients, the value of its `server-buffer-clients` variable will be non-nil.

I'm sure there's a better way, but this code should give a list of buffers with clients:

```
(require 'cl)

(defvar server-buffers nil)

(defun show-server-buffers ()
  (interactive)
  (setq server-buffers nil)
  (let ((original-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (loop for buf in (buffer-list)
      do
      (progn
        (switch-to-buffer buf)
        (if (and
         server-buffer-clients
         (buffer-live-p buf))
        (add-to-list 'server-buffers buf))))
    (switch-to-buffer original-buffer)
    (message "server-buffers: %s" server-buffers)))
```

Comment: Interesting. After editing a commit (and closing its buffer), it says:  server-buffers: (#<killed buffer>).

Comment: Btw.: Is there a better way than saving C-c C-s and then killing the buffer C-c C-k to close such a buffer?

Comment: I've edited my answer to exclude killed buffers, and also to clear my server-buffers variable correctly.

Comment: Falko: You would usually use `C-x #` instead of `C-x k` to tell the server that you have finished with that buffer & client (and you should see a message to this effect when you start the client).

Answer (score 2):

I have adapted `list-processes` for listing clients.
You get a tabulated list of client processes with the newly defined command `list-clients`.
Each client is listed together with the server editing buffer having the client as first entry in `server-buffer-clients`.

```el
(define-derived-mode client-menu-mode process-menu-mode "Client Menu"
  "Major mode for listing the currently connected client processes."
  (remove-hook 'tabulated-list-revert-hook #'list-processes--refresh t)
  (add-hook 'tabulated-list-revert-hook #'server-list-clients--refresh nil t))

(defun server-list-clients (&optional query-only buffer)
  "Display a list of all clients of this emacs session.
If optional argument QUERY-ONLY is non-nil, only processes with
the query-on-exit flag set are listed.
Any process listed as exited or signaled is actually eliminated
after the listing is made.
Optional argument BUFFER specifies a buffer to use, instead of
\"*Client List*\".
The return value is always nil."
  (interactive)
  (or (fboundp 'process-list)
      (error "Asynchronous subprocesses are not supported on this system"))
  (unless (bufferp buffer)
    (setq buffer (get-buffer-create "*Client Process List*")))
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (client-menu-mode)
    (setq process-menu-query-only query-only)
    (server-list-clients--refresh)
    (tabulated-list-print))
  (display-buffer buffer)
  nil)

(defalias #'list-clients #'server-list-clients)

(defun server-client-buffer (client)
  "Return buffer with client in `server-buffer-clients'."
  (catch :found
    (dolist (buf (buffer-list))
      (if (memq client (with-current-buffer buf server-buffer-clients))
          (throw :found buf)))))

(defun server-list-clients--refresh ()
  "Recompute the list of client processes for the Client List buffer.
Also, delete any process that is exited or signaled."
  (setq tabulated-list-entries nil)
  (dolist (p server-clients)
    (cond ((memq (process-status p) '(exit signal closed))
       (delete-process p))
      ((or (not process-menu-query-only)
           (process-query-on-exit-flag p))
       (let* ((buf (server-client-buffer p))
          (type (process-type p))
          (name (process-name p))
          (status (symbol-name (process-status p)))
          (buf-label (if (buffer-live-p buf)
                 `(,(buffer-name buf)
                   face link
                   help-echo ,(format-message
                           "Visit buffer `%s'"
                           (buffer-name buf))
                   follow-link t
                   process-buffer ,buf
                   action process-menu-visit-buffer)
                   "--"))
          (tty (or (process-tty-name p) "--"))
          (cmd
           (if (memq type '(network serial))
               (let ((contact (process-contact p t)))
             (if (eq type 'network)
                 (format "(%s %s)"
                     (if (plist-get contact :type)
                     "datagram"
                       "network")
                     (if (plist-get contact :server)
                     (format "server on %s"
                         (or
                          (plist-get contact :host)
                          (plist-get contact :local)))
                       (format "connection to %s"
                           (plist-get contact :host))))
               (format "(serial port %s%s)"
                   (or (plist-get contact :port) "?")
                   (let ((speed (plist-get contact :speed)))
                     (if speed
                     (format " at %s b/s" speed)
                       "")))))
             (mapconcat 'identity (process-command p) " "))))
         (push (list p (vector name status buf-label tty cmd))
           tabulated-list-entries))))))
```