# Windows Emacs still asking "this emacs session has clients, exit anyway?"

Tags: windows, emacs, save, exit

[new to emacs, new to lisp]

Env:
GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2016-09-17

I run emacs server with EmacsServer-FirstStart.bat:

```
SET HOME=c:\Settings\emacshome
SET EMACS_SERVER_FILE=%HOME%\.emacs.d\server\server
start "runemacs" /MAX "c:\Portableapps\emacs\bin\runemacs.exe"
```

Then I open a txt file, passing it to this emacs.bat:

```
SET HOME=c:\Settings\emacshome
SET EMACS_SERVER_FILE=%HOME%\.emacs.d\server\server 
start "emacs" "c:\Portableapps\emacs\bin\emacsclientw.exe" "%1"
```

When I am done with emacs and I want to reboot, I want to save everything and exit. I run this shortcut on the emacs window:
`C-u C-x C-c`

Does the trick, but I am still asked "this emacs session has clients, exit anyway?"

Why, and how do I get rid of it? I appreciate I could enter [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197517/this-emacs-session-has-clients-how-do-i-find-out-why#comment13098832_10198063):

> You would usually use C-x # instead of C-x k to tell the server that
>   you have finished with that buffer & client (and you should see a
>   message to this effect when you start the client)

However if I do that, I'll have to do that individually for each client/buffer.

PS: I guess I am still somewhat confused about the relationships between clients, servers and buffers.